# Haskell: monadic fixpoint on RWS is looping if traversing on argument

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation, fixed-point-iteration, monadfix

I am writing a program which involves `RWS` for tracking mutable state and producing some log. My purpose is to define a computation that evaluates some action, gathers the aftercoming state and depending on it appends something to the *beginning* of the `Writer`'s log. Minimal example:

```
type M = RWS () String [Int]

run a = evalRWS a () []

prepend s = tell (foldMap show s)

act = do
  tell "a"
  modify (1:)
  tell "b"

comp = mfix $ \s -> prepend s >> act >> get
```

Here I use `MonadFix` to alter the past by writing to the log before the `act` has ever happened. And it works flawlessly returning `"1ab"`. However, if I use the `M` to traverse over the state then it hangs:

```
prepend s = forM_ s (tell . show)
```

This behavior is very strange to me, I don't get why does this computation diverge. It is even harder to justify because the `prepend` in the second variant does not alter the state to any extent. Why doesn't this program converge? Is there anything I can do to fix (inb4 "hehe fix") it?

I know that I can workaround it using `State` part of `RWS`, but for some reason I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `forM_` is not *lazy*. This requirement is explicitly called out in [the `mfix` documentation](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.19/base-4.12.0.0/Control-Monad-Fix.html#v:mfix): the function has to be lazy in order for the fixpoint to converge. But `forM_` does need to destructure its parameter in order to iterate over it. It can still stay lazy with respect to every element of the list, but not the list itself.

---

When you run this recursive-ish computation of yours, it takes three steps (i.e. three monadic binds): `prepend`, then `act`, and then `get`, and as a result you essentially get a value looking like this:

```
[foldMap show s, "a", "b"]
```

Where the `foldMap show s` piece is not yet evaluated - i.e. it's a thunk pointing at `s`, which is the final state of the same computation. It is possible to reference the state to incorporate it into the `foldMap show s` expression before the state is even evaluated, because Haskell is lazy. This is laziness at work.

However, if you replace `prepend` with `foldM_`, you no longer have three steps (three monadic binds) in your computation. Now, you have one step for each element of the resulting state list. Which means that in order to even construct the computation (i.e. define its steps, aka binds) you need to examine its own resulting state.

Answer (score 3):

`forM_ s u` is defined only if `s` is defined, but here `s` is a placeholder passed by `mfix`, which will be defined only once the whole computation `prepend s >> act >> get` terminates.

Your first version works because it doesn't need to inspect the state to put it in a pair.

`mfix :: (a -> m a) -> m a` doesn't accept strict functions `f :: a -> m a` (i.e., such that `f undefined = undefined`).

If you have a list of things to `tell`, then a lazier way is to concatenate them before telling them:

```
prepend s = tell (concatMap show s)
```